# Saving Spark DataFrame as CSV gives InvalidClassException

Tags: apache-spark

I've been using Spark lately and have started running into a problem when trying to save a Spark DataFrame.

If I use the `.save` function overthing works fine:

```
df.write.save("SparkTest_output")
```

But if I try to using the `.csv` or `.json` (or any other extension type). Example:

```
df.write.csv("SparkTest_output")
```

I get a `InvalidClassException`:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local class serialVersionUID = 2
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:621)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)...etc
```

After reading around I learned that this exception can occur with version errors, but I don't know how this could be the case when I'm only running a single file on Spark 2.0.2.1. Has anyone else run into this, or does anyone have any recommendations? Thanks

[Here are the DataFrame write member functions from the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter)

Answer (score 0):

When starting is it possible that the --packages was not defined?

```
spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0 the_script_to_run.py
```

The above example is for a previous databricks dist., use whatever the correct path, versions are. Does this help?

Comment: I didn't specify a package because with Spark 2.0+ support for csv files comes is built in (without needed external packages)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using (verbatim) what's below and got the desired results:

```
df.write.csv(path='path/to/somewhere/in/hdfs', mode='overwrite', sep=',', header=False)
```

Note: If your code (in my case, SQL-like queries) produces no results, the DataFrameWriter won't save anything. So in hindsight, I was thinking that the DataFrameWriter wasn't working, when in all actuality, my query just fetched 0 rows.

Documentation for anyone who stumbles across this: [Spark 2.0.0 DataFrameWriter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter)